# CWnd::KillTimer failed, when I start two timer with same time interval in the main thread

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am confused about how to stop timer in `MFC` application.

I use `SetTimer(2, 1000, NULL)` and `SetTimer(3, 1000, NULL)` at the same time in the maint hread. And there are some loading and uploading tasks inbetween  and when any timer (2 or 3) finished, I just call `CWnd::Killtimer(2)` and `CWnd::Killtimer(3)` in the same time.

BUT, even if Killtimer succeeded, the program just executes the code as if the timer is still set. The `if(true == m_bIsRunning)` condition code, which located in `CWnd::OnTimer` function, fail even if m_bIsRunning actually is with false value.

Comment: How do you know if CWnd::KillTimer() failed? Did you examine the return value? As for getting additional CWnd::OnTimer() events even after the timer is destroyed, this can happen, because there are already more WM_TIMER messages in the message-queue. Quote: *"The WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message. The GetMessage and PeekMessage functions post this message only when no other higher-priority messages are in the thread's message queue. "*

Comment: thanks for your reply. (0) your explanation maybe right as to the WM_TIMER message queue (is this relevant the latter confusion?),,which can be verified by change the timer ID to 1002 and 1003 and it works, return value of CWnd::settimer needs a check too;; (1) and further, when if(true == m_bIsRunning) condition is true even the value of m_bIsRunning is false (so does some pointer points to null) really makes me insane....anyway, thanks bro. :), and i need some test

Comment: [`WM_TIMER` is a *synthesized* message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141204-00/?p=43473). When a timer elapses, a flag is set in the message queue, and when `(Peek|Get)Message()` have no *actual* messages to return, and the flag is set, then `WM_TIMER` is generated and returned immediately. Timers do not post *actual* `WM_TIMER` messages to the queue. So killing a timer should prevent future `WM_TIMER` messages for that timer. If you are getting future `WM_TIMER` messages, then *actual* `WM_TIMER` messages are likely being posted to the message queue via `PostMessage()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) states (SetTimer function):

> Return value
>
> Type:
>
> Type: UINT_PTR
>
> If the function succeeds and the hWnd parameter is NULL, the return
> value is an integer identifying the new timer. An application can pass
> this value to the KillTimer function to destroy the timer.

You should pass those returned values instead of 2 and 3 to KillTimer()